# Extrema Function of $2$ variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I do not know how to set this problem up. Any insight as to how to get the equation would be great.

It is John's birthday and his parents want to make him a cake in the shape of a rectangular box. The height of the cake will be $15$ centimeters, and $2$ times the width plus $2$ times the length will be $180$ centimeters. Find the largest possible volume of cake that John can receive. Round your answer to $5$ decimal places.

Comment: Hem, there are three variables, not two. They are linked by two equations, hence only one degree of freedom remains.

Answer (score 1):

$L + W = 90 \to V =f(L)= L\times W\times H = 15L(90-L)\to f'(L) = 15(90-2L)=0 \iff L = 45 \to W = 45$. Thus $V_{max} = 15\times 45\times 45 = ....$

Answer (score 0):

Only the base are matters, as the height is fixed.

Then, $w+l=90$. You need to maximize $wl=w(90-w)$.

By canceling the derivative, $90-2w=0$, or $w=45$, and $l=45$. The largest area (volume) is given by a square (square prism).

Answer (score 0):

We have $W+L=90$. Consider $W=L=45$ and then consider $W=45-k, L=45+k$. It is well known that $(45-k)(45+k)$ is maximum when $k=0$. In fact, this justifies the initial assumption.